# Is there a easy way to do a group by in Python to aggregate a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with fields as follow

| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 7 |

I would like aggregate `field_2` i.e:

| field_1 | field_2 | field_3 | field_2_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 4 | 7 |
| B | 5 | 7 | 7 |

I usually create a new dataframe by doing a `groupby` on the dataframe with the field I want and then `merge` back the grouped dataframe to the original one. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `df['field_2_agg'] = df['field_2'].sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['field_2_agg'] = df['field_2'].sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  field_1  field_2  field_3  field_2_agg
0       A        2        4            7
1       B        5        7            7
```